# fullsize cover is zooming

Tags: html, css

I have a picture I have to use for a fullsize cover picture for a landingpage. The picture is 3680 * 2456px. When I set the picture in my code, the picture is zooming, which means I can see the half of the picture. Therefore I tried to resize it to 1024 * 683 px, which resultet in that my picture filled the half of the banner.

How can I make my picture fit my banner, so it is not zooming?

```css
.fullscreen {
        width:100%;
        min-height:100%;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:50% 50%;
        background-position:50% 50%\9 !important;
        background-image:url(/img/seminar/bg.jpg);
        background-size
    }
    .overlay {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen landing parallax">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <!-- /.logo -->
                            <div class="logo"><a href="https://site.dk/"><img src="http://site.dk/img/site-logo-white.png" alt="logo"></a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
.fullscreen {
        background: url(/img/seminar/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

instead of your original `.fullscreen` CSS.

This snippet of code can be found via CSS Tricks website.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. The picture zoomed some out now. I am just gonna try to resize the pixel of the picture. Maybe that could give the last

Comment: No that did not do anything to resize to 1840 px. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: I have tested this with an image exactly the same size and it doesn't cause a zoom. you could add `max-width: 1840px;` to the code.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Set the image height and width to 100%

```
<img src="http://site.dk/img/site-logo-white.png" alt="logo" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
```

**Edit**: To do that in `CSS` try this

```
.fullscreen img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your comment. I would like to do it in CSS. I just tried to do this, but it is still not working: `.fullscreen {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-position:50% 50%\9 !important;
    background-image:url(/img/seminar/bg.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}`